# Matlab Matrix Dataset Comparison and Certain Output

Tags: matlab, matrix, dataset, comparison, match

if I have matrices A & B: A=[400(rows)x60(columns)] B=[150x60] (Note:That matrix B has fixed columns=60, but the rows are variable could change from 1-400)

I will enter these two matrices into matlab, matrix A is fixed and uploaded to matlab as an excel file, while matrix B is measured directly from the code.(Note:Both matrices contain numerical values)

Now what I want help with is the following: I want to compare the data I'm getting from matrix B with matrix A CONTINUOUSLY, if the values in B are CLOSE (NOT NECESSARILY EQUAL) to the values of A then the matlab outputs lets say True. If the values in B are NOT CLOSE or completely distant from the values of A, then output False. (Note: I don't know but maybe we should use a certain threshold to determine the range of closeness of values between A and B, if we should have a certain threshold, lets say the threshold should be 70%)

Please if anyone has an answer or could help, I need the program. I'm using Matlab 2014a. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you _need the program_, don't rely on someone else to do it for you in their spare time. Do it yourself; and if you get stuck with something _specific_, ask about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy!.

Suppose you have your matrix in the file `A.xlsx`,sheet `Sheet1` and the matrix `B` in matlab already.

Also, let's say that, under this context, that `CLOSE` is some operator between `A` and `B`, up to the `m`-th row, for example the `norm`, with `m` taking any value from 1 to 400.

`Norm(A-Bm)=|A-Bm|= SUM_i=1^m SUM_j=1^60 (a(i,j)-bm(i,j))^2`

Let's define a threshold, for example `0.1*Norm(An)*Norm(Bn)`.

Hence, the code for that is the following:

```
function result=matrixcomparison(Bm)
% Read A Matrix
A=xlsread('A');
[ma,na]=size(A); %ma is always 400, na is always 60
[mb,nb]=size(Bm); %mb is variant, na is always 60
% Make a Projection Matrix
Am=A(1:mb,1:nb);
%Compute the norm
normABm=norm(Am-Bm);
%Compare
if (normABm>0.1*norm(Am)*norm(Bm))
    disp('Matrices are different.');
    result= 0;
else
    disp('Matrices are equal.');
    result= 1;
end
```

You save the above code under the file `matrixcomparison.m`

Of course, this dont have any 'Continuous' comparison. which you should make on the following sense:

```
for m=1:400
    % Read B
    <<Calculate B for m>>
    % Calculate Norm
    result(m)=matrixcomparison(Bm);   
end
% Plot the results
plot(results);
```

You paste the second above code onto another `Script` and just run it.

Cheers,...